# How to unmark for delete files in Perforce P4V that were accidentally deleted from the local workspace

Tags: java, perforce, p4v

I have accidentally deleted files from my local work space of perforce and now they are showing as "mark for delete" in P4V. I have tried below steps but still the mark is not going

1. Get Latest Revision(Force Operation)
2. Revert Files

Can someone please guide me on the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Revert Files" is the correct command to run any time you want to discard changes to an open file.  In the case of a file that's opened for delete, "revert" will restore the revision you had synced from the depot prior to opening the file for delete.

If "revert" is not working, look in the log pane for an error message.